# Simple HTML Dom - parse only few columns from original table

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I want to copy some table to my website, but only with few specific columns

Here is my code

```
<?php

require('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://pomorskifutbol.pl/liga.php?id=970');

$table = $html->find('table', 0);
$rowData = array();

foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
    // initialize array to store the cell data from each row
    $flight = array();
    foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
        // push the cell's text to the array
        $flight[] = $cell->plaintext;
    }
    $rowData[] = $flight;
}

echo '<table>';
foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
    echo '<tr>'; 
    foreach ($tr as $td)
        echo '<td>' . $td .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

[whole table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnWdY.png)
And this prints whole table, I want to get only few columns, for example only "M.", "Drużyna", "M", "PKT"
How extract only this columns from this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the entry:

```
foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
```

to

```
foreach($row->find('td') as $columnNumber => $cell) {
```

and make an if before the filling of the $flights array, e.g

```
//somewhere in code
$columnNumbers = [ 0, 2, 3,4, 7];

// int the foreach loop
if ( in_array( $columnNumber, $columnNumbers ) ) {
 $flight[] = $cell->plaintext;
}
```

PS. Powodzenia :)

Comment: Works great! Just one more question - how to ignore first row of this table? (Mecze bezpośrednie) PS. Dzięki :)

Comment: The first column has the index 0 - so the $columnNumbers should not have this index

Comment: This data is in row 0, column 1. Other cells in this row is empty, and I need column number 1, but not this row 0. So how I can skip row 0?

Comment: foreach($table->find('tr') as $rowNumber => $row) {
if ( $rowNumber == 0 ) continue;
....

Comment: GREAT! Thanks a lot :)